# Change shard size when converting keras model to tfjs for react-native

Tags: react-native, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to convert a keras model into tensorflowjs so that it can be run with react-native.

React-native seems to only support tfjs models that have 1 shard.

Is there anyway to combine my shards into 1 shard, or change the shard size when converting so that I only end up with one shard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to specify the shard file size. The bigger is the size, the less number of files, there will be. The shard file size can be specified with the option `--weight_shard_size_bytes` of `tfjs_converter`